# Kotlin classes not identified as Flink valid POJO's

Tags: kotlin, apache-flink

I am writing a Flink application in Kotlin and data classes (as well as other Kotlin classes) are not identified as valid POJO types.

The Flink documentation states that a data type is recognized as a POJO type (and allows "by-name" field referencing) if the following conditions are fulfilled:

- The class is public and standalone
- The class has a public no-argument constructor
- All non-static, non-transient fields in the class are either public (and non-final) or have public getter and setter methods that follow Java beans naming conventions.

I receive the following when implementing a Kotlin data class, which should meet the aforementioned conditions to be recognized as a POJO:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor - 
Class class <Class> cannot be used as a POJO type because not all 
fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. 
Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" 
for details of the effect on performance.
```

Investigating further, I reviewed Flink's TypeExtractor.isValidPojoField method @ https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/typeutils/TypeExtractor.java

In a separate project, I applied the field checks with java.lang.reflect.Modifier on a simple Kotlin data class in attempt to narrow down the issue.

```
data class SomeDataClass(
    val topic: String = "",
    val message: String = ""
)
```

While Kotlin class fields have public visibility by default, Modifier.isPublic recognizes the fields as private. Additionally, Modifier.isFinal recognizes the fields as final.

```
val clazz = SomeDataClass::class.java
val fields = clazz.declaredFields
fields.forEach { it ->
    println("field: $it")
    println(it.genericType)
    println("public? " + Modifier.isPublic(it.modifiers))
    println("final? " + Modifier.isFinal(it.modifiers))
    println("transient? " + Modifier.isTransient(it.modifiers))
    println("static? " + Modifier.isStatic(it.modifiers))
}

>
field: private final java.lang.String SomeDataClass.topic
class java.lang.String
public? false
final? true
transient? false
static? false
```

However, public getter and setter methods are created for these fields, so this object should still meet the POJO criteria.

```
println(clazz.declaredMethods.toList())

>
[public boolean SomeDataClass.equals(java.lang.Object), 
public java.lang.String SomeDataClass.toString(), 
public int SomeDataClass.hashCode(), 
**public final java.lang.String SomeDataClass.getMessage(),** 
public final SomeDataClass SomeDataClass.copy(java.lang.String,java.lang.String), 
**public final java.lang.String SomeDataClass.getTopic(),** 
public final java.lang.String SomeDataClass.component1(), 
public final java.lang.String SomeDataClass.component2(), 
public static SomeDataClass SomeDataClass.copy$default(SomeDataClass,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.Object)]
```

The getter and setter methods, however, are final, which leads me to believe this is the issue.

I am relatively new to JVM development, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have reviewed the Flink Jira, Stack Overflow, and Flink mailing list and have not found a similar issue reported.

Comment: If the problem turns out to only be the final modifiers of the data classes you can use the "all-open" kotlin plugin to remove them from the compiled code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least two POJO rules violation with provided data class.

1) The class has a public no-argument constructor

By default, Kotlin will not generate overloads to functions with default parameter values (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation)

So your compiled class will have only one constructor with two-parameter constructor, and no-argument constructor will not be created. To force Kotlin compiler to generate multiple overloads one should use `@JvmOverloads` annotation. In your case it will be used on constructor so we also need to add `constructor` keyword:

```
data class SomeDataClass @JvmOverloads constructor
```

2) All non-static, non-transient fields in the class are either public (and non-final) or have public getter and setter methods that follow Java beans naming conventions.

Since you are using `val` keywords the generated fields will be `final`, and no setter will be generated for them. So you can change `val`s to `var`s and the fields will no longer be `final` and proper getters and setters will be generated too. (Or you could use another annotation to prevent generating getters and setters and expose a field as it is https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields)

So final code should be like this:

```
data class SomeDataClass @JvmOverloads constructor(
    var topic: String = "",
    var message: String = ""
)
```

Comment: First problem doesn't apply, from the documentation you linked: "if a class has default values for all constructor parameters, a public no-argument constructor will be generated for it. This works even if the `@JvmOverloads` annotation is not specified."

Comment: Hey there. I am considering writing a Flink topology in Kotlin. So the issue here was solved by changing the `vals` to `vars`? Thanks for posting the question!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use kotlin data classes without any modifications to match a Java POJO (i.e: no default/null values required and keep using `val`).

You can either:

1. provide a custom [Kryo serializer](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/third_party_serializers/) to serialize it using Protobuf or Avro (or the tool and format of your choice).
2. use a [Kotlin friendly type serializer](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flink-kotlin) that will serialize your data class similarly to a [case class](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/types_serialization/#supported-data-types).

Comment: For option 2, adding `@TypeInfo(DataClassTypeInfoFactory::class)` worked like a charm.